# Way to exclude all subsequent rows after an uncontinuous order

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Story:**

I am looking at continuous records based on a 1 month interval. As soon as this rule is broken, any subsequent rows should be excluded from the list. Even if the continuous rule reoccurs later in the future

**Sample Data:**

```
+----------------+---------+------------+
| date_purchased | product | date_rebill |
+----------------+---------+------------+
| 2019-01-01     | a       | 2019-02-01 |
| 2019-01-01     | a       | 2019-03-01 |
| 2019-01-01     | a       | 2019-04-01 |
| 2019-01-01     | a       | 2019-06-01 |
| 2019-01-01     | a       | 2019-07-01 |
| 2019-01-01     | a       | 2019-08-01 |
| 2019-02-01     | b       | 2019-05-01 |
| 2019-02-01     | b       | 2019-06-01 |
+----------------+---------+------------+
```

In this example May is mising for product A, therefore june and july records should be excluded.
As for product B, there should be no records or at least the count should be 0 for rebill. This is because the first rebill happens more than a month after the first date purchased

**Query:**

I started with something like that. Now I have '1' for consecutive months. The issue is that I can't filter the data set to `diff = 1` due to consecutive rows happening after a break has happened.

```
select
  date_puchased
  ,product
  ,datediff(month,previous_date,date_rebill) as diff
from (
    select date_purchased
       , product
       , date_rebill
       , lag(date_rebill,1,date_purchased) 
          over (partition by product order by date_purchased ASC) as previous_date
    from table
) as base
```

**My Objective:**

My objective here is remove any future rows as soon as the "consecutiveness" rule is broken

Comment: Isnt clear why b should be excluded. doesnt seem to have missing row if start with 05

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza because 3 months after the date_purchased. let me clarify this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use `row_number()` and arithmetic

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by product order by date_rebill) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where datediff(month, date_purchased, date_rebill) = seqnum;
```

Comment: im not sure how this excludes non continous intervals between rebills dates.

Comment: I think you want `where datediff(month, date_purchased, date_rebill) = seqnum;` check fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/57dba/2

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza . . . Yes, thank you.  I was phrasing the problem as the inverse problem of getting bad rows.  My confusion.